# Upgrading Mercurial 1.5 to 2.2

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I am upgrading my server from an old version of Mercurial, 1.5 to the newest version.  I am wondering if the 2.2 build of Mercurial is stable for use by multiple users at a time.  Also are there any gotchas when upgrading like my custom hooks not working, or a buildslave object not working?  I have not done a major upgrade on a source control server before so help would be appreciated.

Comment: So how did it go? Can you share something results?

Comment: The upgrade went smoothly.  I was not prepared for the changes in Case roll ups.  However, since I did not have to re-write my really old hook for those, the change in Mercurial made it much simpler.  The amazing documentation and API calls provided by the Mercurial authors made everything go better too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mercurial is famouse for being very strict regarding compatibility. Have you checked [upgrade notes](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UpgradeNotes)? It list all breaking changes between version. Biggest change for me is introduction of `hgweb` in 1.6.

Biggest exception from compatibility rules are hooks. Mercurial doesn't guarantee anything so only way is to try.

Also consider making update in two stages. For example first to 1.9 and than to 2.2.